# What's the purpose of using semicolon in if condition?

Tags: java, android

I am following a tutorial [Creating custom Android views](http://www.jayway.com/2012/12/12/creating-custom-android-views-part-4-measuring-and-how-to-force-a-view-to-be-square/) where the author write this `if-else` condition. Here's the condition.

```
if (width &gt; height) {
        size = height;
    } else {
        size = width;
    }
```

I can't understand this line   `if (width &gt; height).` Could anyone please clarify me the condition?

Comment: That's just an error in how the webpage rendered and/or the HTML for that page. It should be `if (width > height)`

Comment: All it means is the author screwed up their webpage. It's HTML for >.

Comment: &gt; is actually  > (greater than symbol)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For HTML `&gt;` stands for `>` sign.

Hence it will be like below,

```
if ( width > height )
```

Answer (score 3):

`&gt;` is character entity reference for `>` character in HTML because browser thinks it is starting a tag. so therefore it is replaced with `&gt;`

so your code is actually this

```
if (width > height) {
        size = height;
    } else {
        size = width;
    }
```